# Matching two values for multiple columns. i cant figure how to approach it

Tags: excel, vba

i have 6 columns

Grade,Date, ID number, Grade Old, date old and ID number

I need the grade to look for value in grade old and also date old of the grade needs to be within 2 weeks of the date then the ID number is same.

for example:

if grade = A then it needs to look for A in Grade Old and also compare the dates, if the date old is 2 weeks of date then ID number stays the same.
(There can be multiple Grades i.e. Grade old can have multiple entries as A, just need to pick the right one by comparing dates.)

I have no idea how do i achieve this. I tried a few codes but in vain.

Thank you for your time.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: What happens if no same grade is found, that is within two weeks? And you keep talking about ID number, but which one do you mean? The left one?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Yeah for the ID number,left one goes into the right one. and if no same grade is found nothing happens, just leave the cell blank.

Comment: Still not sure if I understand correctly: so you want to go through each "grade", and if there is a matching "grade old" within two weeks of "date", you want "ID left" to be written into "ID right"? And all other "IDs right" remain untouched. That right? Also, is there more than one match that is within two weeks?

Comment: yeah that is right! and nope there won't be more than one match within two weeks. Thanks :)

Comment: the grades (left), are they unique? or can there also be multiple A s on the left side?

Comment: There can be multiples A's on left as well. Thanks

Comment: Ok, what happens, if there is two A's on the left that are let's say 3 weeks apart. And on the right side, there is an A that is right in between those 3 weeks. Which ID should it get?

Comment: That can't happen but if it does it will get the one on the left. thanks :)

Comment: ok check my answer, the code works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this code a try. This should do what you want, based on your comments above.

Note on data structure:

- Grade is in column A, Row 1 are the headers.
- My sheet is called "Grades"

Change the code according to your sheet structure.

```
Sub grades()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim firstrow, lastrow As Integer

Dim firstAddress As String
Dim tmpFind As Range
Dim grade As String
Dim dateLeft As Double
Dim dateOld As Double

Dim found As Boolean

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Grades")    'change "Grades" to the name of your sheet


    With ws

        firstrow = 2

        lastrow = .Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row

        For r = firstrow To lastrow

            found = False

            grade = .Range("A" & r).Value
            dateLeft = .Range("B" & r).Value

            Set tmpFind = .Range("D" & firstrow & ":D" & lastrow).Find(grade, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            If Not tmpFind Is Nothing Then

                firstAddress = tmpFind.Address

                Do

                    dateOld = .Range("E" & tmpFind.Row).Value

                    'check if dateOld is within + - two weeks. if + 2 weeks not required, remove 'And dateOld <= dateLeft + 14' from below
                    If dateOld >= dateLeft - 14 And dateOld <= dateLeft + 14 Then

                        .Range("F" & tmpFind.Row).Value = .Range("C" & r).Value     'writes ID-left to ID-right
                        found = True

                    End If

                    Set tmpFind = .Range("D" & firstrow & ":D" & lastrow).FindNext(tmpFind)

                Loop While Not tmpFind Is Nothing And tmpFind.Address <> firstAddress And found = False

            End If

        Next r

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: my friend you are a living legend! an angel sent from heavens.
I literally spent a week trying to do this! Thanks a lot i really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad it helped! You should step through the code (with F8) and get to understand it. Then you'll also be able to solve other questions in the future. :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a Excel Macro to do this?
You may use the below formulae
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(,A:A, 0)), "No Match", "Match")

=IF(G2="Match",IF(B2-E2<15,C2,F2),)

[image: this is how it looks]

If you are looking for an excel macro then you may use try using the same sort of validation in your logic. Hope this helps.. thanks.

-Codekavi.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your reply.
The thing is what if you have multiple entries in GradeOLD how will it pick the right one as dates may vary.

Comment: For example:
A12 = "A",B12="5 June", D6 = "A",E6 = "4th June". in this case i would want the Grade to match D6 not D2,, if that helps.

Comment: Thank you code for your reply and time. This was indeed ingenious but i couldn't get it working with duplicates.